# backbone view doesn't render correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

i've created a view to render a collection fetched by parse.com but if i call the view passing it a collection doesn't work.

The function that fetch and send to view:

```
friends: function () {

    var self = this;
    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var Amici = Parse.Object.extend("User");

    var query = new Parse.Query(User);
    query.equalTo("objectId", Parse.User.current().id);
    query.find({
        success: function (user) {
            for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {

                user[i].relation("amici").query().find({

                    success: function (amici) {

                        console.log(amici);
                        var friendscollection = new Amicizie(amici);
                        console.log(friendscollection);
                        var page = new Homelistuser({
                            model: friendscollection
                        });
                        self.changePage(page);

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
},
```

the console log of friends collection is:

```
child {length: 3, models: Array[3], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User"…}
```

it seems be a correct collection to pass to view but don't render correctly.Ad example this collection render correctly:

```
child {length: 5, models: Array[5], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, model: function…}
```

Why the first collection doesn't work while the last works?

models:Array[] of collection that works is:

```
Models: Array[5] 
0: child
1: child
2: child 
3: child
```

while models:Array[] of collection that doesn't work is:

```
models: Array[3] 
0: Backbone.Model 
1: Backbone.Model 
2: Backbone.Model
```

the view:

```
var Homelistuser = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "ul",
    id: "list",

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        $(window).on('orientationchange', this.onOrientationChange);
        $(".out").on('click', this.log_out);
        $(".prove").on('click', this.prove);
    },
    events: {
        "click .out": "log_out"

    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).empty();
        _.each(this.model.models, function (ad) {


            $(this.el).append(new SingleUserView({
                model: ad
            }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },
```

view called by first view:

```
var SingleUserView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "li",

    events: {
        "click": "goToDetails",
            "click .out": "log_out"
    },

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
        var ad = this.model.toJSON();
        console.log(ad);
        ad.cid = this.model.cid;
        $(this.el).html(this.template(ad));
        return this;
    },
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?" And can you clarify exactly which collection does work?

Comment: Probably some of the models are not valid. The quoted collection info is not too useful, as the real infromation is in the `models: Array[3]` element

Comment: This collection works:child {length: 5, models: Array[5], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, model: function…}. This doesn't work:child {length: 3, models: Array[3], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User"…}.

Comment: models:Array[] of collection that works is: Models: Array[5]
0: child
1: child
2: child
3: child
while models:Array[] of collection that doesn't work is:models: Array[3]
0: Backbone.Model
1: Backbone.Model
2: Backbone.Model